# PayPal-Response was not successful: Express Checkout PayerID is missing - Symfony 2.5 JMSPaymentPayPalbundle and JMSPaymentCoreBundle

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, jmspaymentpaypalbundle

I have problem with my application Symfony 2.5. I want to integrate Paypal Express checkout but get information:

```
PayPal-Response was not successful: Debug-Token: 27b2ab3a5b382 10419: Express Checkout PayerID is missing. (Express Checkout PayerID is missing.)10406: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See a`enter code here`dditional error messages for details. (The PayerID value is invalid.)
```

I am using a Paypal Sandbox account. I created App, then I went to Account Details / API Credentials and copied to app / config.yml username, password and signature. Transaction data is saved to the orders and payments table.
The controller "/orders/8/payment/create" also gets an error "User must authorize the transaction". But after reloading the page I get a flicker above.

config.yml

```html
jms_payment_core: 
    encryption: 
        secret: def00000093fb9f5f5b2c8657099xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxec66409b58b5ee91e0be53f836bb05ea6c91aeaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

jms_payment_paypal:
    username: poczta-facilitator_api1.xxxxx.pl
    password: KVGAQBAxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    signature: Aaose356mD-hOFG7cGBTPyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    return_url: https://xxxxxxx
    cancel_url: https://xxxxxxx
    debug: true
```

OrdersController.php

```html
<?php

namespace Adevo\AdminBundle\Controller;


use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Form\ChoosePaymentMethodType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\PluginController\Result;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Adevo\AdminBundle\Entity\Order;

/**
 * @Route("/orders")
 */
class OrdersController extends Controller {

    /**
     * @Route(
     * "/new/{amount}"
     * )
     */
    public function newAction($amount) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $order = new Order($amount);
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_orders_show', [
                            'id' => $order->getId(),
        ]));

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/show",
     * name="app_orders_show"
     * )
     * @Template
     */
    public function showAction(Request $request, Order $order) {
        $form = $this->createForm('jms_choose_payment_method', null, [
            'amount' => $order->getAmount(),
            'currency' => 'EUR',
            'default_method' => 'payment_paypal', // Optional
//            'predefined_data' => array(
//                'paypal_express_checkout' => array(
//                    'return_url' => $this->router->generate('payment_complete', array(
//                        'orderNumber' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
//                    ), true),
//                    'cancel_url' => $this->router->generate('payment_cancel', array(
//                        'orderNumber' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
//                    ), true)
//                ),
//            ),
        ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $ppc = $this->get('payment.plugin_controller');
            $ppc->createPaymentInstruction($instruction = $form->getData());

            $order->setPaymentInstruction($instruction);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($order);
            $em->flush($order);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_orders_paymentcreate', [
                                'id' => $order->getId(),
            ]));
        }

        return [
            'order' => $order,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ];
    }

    private function createPayment($order) {
        $instruction = $order->getPaymentInstruction();
        $pendingTransaction = $instruction->getPendingTransaction();

        if ($pendingTransaction !== null) {
            return $pendingTransaction->getPayment();
        }

        $ppc = $this->get('payment.plugin_controller');
        $amount = $instruction->getAmount() - $instruction->getDepositedAmount();

        return $ppc->createPayment($instruction->getId(), $amount);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/payment/create",
     * name="app_orders_paymentcreate"
     * )
     * 
     */
    public function paymentCreateAction(Order $order) {
        $payment = $this->createPayment($order);

        $ppc = $this->get('payment.plugin_controller');
        $result = $ppc->approveAndDeposit($payment->getId(), $payment->getTargetAmount());

        if ($result->getStatus() === Result::STATUS_SUCCESS) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_orders_paymentcomplete', [
                                'id' => $order->getId(),
            ]));
        }

        throw $result->getPluginException();
        //return new Response('Payment not complete');

        // In a real-world application you wouldn't throw the exception. You would,
        // for example, redirect to the showAction with a flash message informing
        // the user that the payment was not successful.
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/payment/complete",
     * name="app_orders_paymentcomplete"
     * )
     * 
     */
    public function paymentCompleteAction(Order $order) {
        return new Response('Payment complete');
    }

}
```

Order.php -> Entity

```html
<?php

namespace Adevo\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\PaymentInstruction;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\PaymentInstruction") */
    private $paymentInstruction;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=5) */
    private $amount;

    public function __construct($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function getPaymentInstruction()
    {
        return $this->paymentInstruction;
    }

    public function setPaymentInstruction(PaymentInstruction $instruction)
    {
        $this->paymentInstruction = $instruction;
    }
}
```

```html
Logs   - 1 error
INFO - Matched route "app_orders_paymentcreate" (parameters: "_controller": "Adevo\AdminBundle\Controller\OrdersController::paymentCreateAction", "id": "12", "_route": "app_orders_paymentcreate") 
DEBUG - Read SecurityContext from the session 
DEBUG - Reloading user from user provider. 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.google_id AS google_id_2, t0.username AS username_3, t0.name AS name_4, t0.surname AS surname_5, t0.description AS description_6, t0.email AS email_7, t0.password AS password_8, t0.account_non_expired AS account_non_expired_9, t0.account_non_locked AS account_non_locked_10, t0.credentials_non_expired AS credentials_non_expired_11, t0.enabled AS enabled_12, t0.roles AS roles_13, t0.action_token AS action_token_14, t0.register_date AS register_date_15, t0.avatar AS avatar_16, t0.updateDate AS updateDate_17 FROM users t0 WHERE t0.id = ? 
DEBUG - Username "tomek" was reloaded from user provider. 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.amount AS amount_2, t0.paymentInstruction_id AS paymentInstruction_id_3 FROM orders t0 WHERE t0.id = ? 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.amount AS amount_1, t0.approved_amount AS approved_amount_2, t0.approving_amount AS approving_amount_3, t0.created_at AS created_at_4, t0.credited_amount AS credited_amount_5, t0.crediting_amount AS crediting_amount_6, t0.currency AS currency_7, t0.deposited_amount AS deposited_amount_8, t0.depositing_amount AS depositing_amount_9, t0.extended_data AS extended_data_10, t0.payment_system_name AS payment_system_name_11, t0.reversing_approved_amount AS reversing_approved_amount_12, t0.reversing_credited_amount AS reversing_credited_amount_13, t0.reversing_deposited_amount AS reversing_deposited_amount_14, t0.state AS state_15, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_16, t0.id AS id_17 FROM payment_instructions t0 WHERE t0.id = ? 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.approved_amount AS approved_amount_1, t0.approving_amount AS approving_amount_2, t0.credited_amount AS credited_amount_3, t0.crediting_amount AS crediting_amount_4, t0.deposited_amount AS deposited_amount_5, t0.depositing_amount AS depositing_amount_6, t0.expiration_date AS expiration_date_7, t0.reversing_approved_amount AS reversing_approved_amount_8, t0.reversing_credited_amount AS reversing_credited_amount_9, t0.reversing_deposited_amount AS reversing_deposited_amount_10, t0.state AS state_11, t0.target_amount AS target_amount_12, t0.attention_required AS attention_required_13, t0.expired AS expired_14, t0.created_at AS created_at_15, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_16, t0.id AS id_17, t0.payment_instruction_id AS payment_instruction_id_18 FROM payments t0 WHERE t0.payment_instruction_id = ? 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.attention_required AS attention_required_1, t0.created_at AS created_at_2, t0.credited_amount AS credited_amount_3, t0.crediting_amount AS crediting_amount_4, t0.reversing_amount AS reversing_amount_5, t0.state AS state_6, t0.target_amount AS target_amount_7, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_8, t0.id AS id_9, t0.payment_instruction_id AS payment_instruction_id_10, t0.payment_id AS payment_id_11 FROM credits t0 WHERE t0.payment_instruction_id = ? 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.amount AS amount_1, t0.approved_amount AS approved_amount_2, t0.approving_amount AS approving_amount_3, t0.created_at AS created_at_4, t0.credited_amount AS credited_amount_5, t0.crediting_amount AS crediting_amount_6, t0.currency AS currency_7, t0.deposited_amount AS deposited_amount_8, t0.depositing_amount AS depositing_amount_9, t0.extended_data AS extended_data_10, t0.payment_system_name AS payment_system_name_11, t0.reversing_approved_amount AS reversing_approved_amount_12, t0.reversing_credited_amount AS reversing_credited_amount_13, t0.reversing_deposited_amount AS reversing_deposited_amount_14, t0.state AS state_15, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_16, t0.id AS id_17 FROM payment_instructions t0 WHERE t0.id = ? LIMIT 1 
DEBUG - "START TRANSACTION" 
DEBUG - INSERT INTO payments (approved_amount, approving_amount, credited_amount, crediting_amount, deposited_amount, depositing_amount, expiration_date, reversing_approved_amount, reversing_credited_amount, reversing_deposited_amount, state, target_amount, attention_required, expired, created_at, updated_at, payment_instruction_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
DEBUG - "COMMIT" 
DEBUG - "START TRANSACTION" 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.approved_amount AS approved_amount_1, t0.approving_amount AS approving_amount_2, t0.credited_amount AS credited_amount_3, t0.crediting_amount AS crediting_amount_4, t0.deposited_amount AS deposited_amount_5, t0.depositing_amount AS depositing_amount_6, t0.expiration_date AS expiration_date_7, t0.reversing_approved_amount AS reversing_approved_amount_8, t0.reversing_credited_amount AS reversing_credited_amount_9, t0.reversing_deposited_amount AS reversing_deposited_amount_10, t0.state AS state_11, t0.target_amount AS target_amount_12, t0.attention_required AS attention_required_13, t0.expired AS expired_14, t0.created_at AS created_at_15, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_16, t0.id AS id_17, t0.payment_instruction_id AS payment_instruction_id_18 FROM payments t0 WHERE t0.id = ? FOR UPDATE 
DEBUG - SELECT t0.extended_data AS extended_data_1, t0.processed_amount AS processed_amount_2, t0.reason_code AS reason_code_3, t0.reference_number AS reference_number_4, t0.requested_amount AS requested_amount_5, t0.response_code AS response_code_6, t0.state AS state_7, t0.created_at AS created_at_8, t0.updated_at AS updated_at_9, t0.tracking_id AS tracking_id_10, t0.transaction_type AS transaction_type_11, t0.id AS id_12, t0.credit_id AS credit_id_13, t0.payment_id AS payment_id_14 FROM financial_transactions t0 WHERE t0.payment_id = ? 
DEBUG - INSERT INTO financial_transactions (extended_data, processed_amount, reason_code, reference_number, requested_amount, response_code, state, created_at, updated_at, tracking_id, transaction_type, credit_id, payment_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
DEBUG - UPDATE payment_instructions SET approving_amount = ?, depositing_amount = ?, extended_data = ?, updated_at = ? WHERE id = ? 
DEBUG - UPDATE payments SET approving_amount = ?, depositing_amount = ?, state = ?, updated_at = ? WHERE id = ? 
DEBUG - "COMMIT" 
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\Exception\ActionRequiredException: "User must authorize the transaction." at /home/users/adevo/public_html/babayaga.adevo.pl/vendor/jms/payment-paypal-bundle/JMS/Payment/PaypalBundle/Plugin/ExpressCheckoutPlugin.php line 303 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". 
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". 
WARNING - Defining the initRuntime() method in the "form" extension is deprecated since version 1.23. Use the `needs_environment` option to get the Twig_Environment instance in filters, functions, or tests; or explicitly implement Twig_Extension_InitRuntimeInterface if needed (not recommended). 
WARNING - Defining the initRuntime() method in the "adevo_news_extension" extension is deprecated since version 1.23. Use the `needs_environment` option to get the Twig_Environment instance in filters, functions, or tests; or explicitly implement Twig_Extension_InitRuntimeInterface if needed (not recommended). 
WARNING - Defining the initRuntime() method in the "adevo_admin_extension" extension is deprecated since version 1.23. Use the `needs_environment` option to get the Twig_Environment instance in filters, functions, or tests; or explicitly implement Twig_Extension_InitRuntimeInterface if needed (not recommended).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrHmV.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXF9D.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5msZ.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIiuA.jpg)

Comment: Can you paste the JSON request / response ?

Comment: Where can I get json code request / response with Paypal?

Comment: You need to log it within your code

Comment: I added the logs

Comment: This logs are not providing the details unfortunately - let's try it another way after you get the error user has not authorized the transaction so you go to the approval URL and approve the transaction

Comment: I added screenshot with logs -> "User must authorize the transaction."

Comment: When I enter the payment summary link /orders/18/payment/complete I get the error -> screenshot 3

Comment: To resolve this error "User must authorize the transaction" are you first approving the payment on paypal ?

Comment: I do not know what it means to approve the payment on paypal, how do I check it? In my Paypal account I have created a REST Api App. In the config.yml file, however, I did not provide data for this application only from Sandbox Accounts mail-facilitator @ tomekxxxxxxx. Nowhere in the application is the configured payer data. Maybe the default payer is post-buyer @ tomekkxxxxxxxx? Paypal Configuration -> picture 4

Comment: do you have the code to handle offsite payment ?
 http://jmspaymentcorebundle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/accepting_payments.html#performing-the-payment-offsite

Comment: After adding this code, you will redirect to Paypal, login and transaction. Thanks great for the help.

Comment: Where in the back of the paypal test account can I find tested test payments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add code to handle offsite payments

http://jmspaymentcorebundle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/accepting_payments.html#performing-the-payment-offsite